# Re-Order Name Field and other fields in the Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to reorder the columns in the document library that's associated with my custom content types when end user uploads a document.I am having few  columns col1, col2, col3, col4,col5 where col2, col4 are mandatory.So i need to get the Name of the file as the first item, when the user uploads the document then col2, and col4.How to do this using PowerShell.

I tried with the code with the InternalNames of the columns:

```
      function ResetColumnOrderInListCT($siteurl,$columnorder)
      {
      foreach($ContentType in $ContentTypes)
          {
              $ctype = $list.contenttypes[$ContentType]
              $newFieldOrderfromxml = $colorder
              $newfieldorder = $newFieldOrder.Split(',')
              $ctype.FieldLinks.Reorder($newFieldOrder)
              $ctype.update()
              #$result.Add($ctype)
              Write-Host "Reordered fields for" $web.title "-" 
              $list.title "-" $ContentType
          }
        }
      ResetColumnOrderInListCT "http://sirvr1:123/sites/IT"  
      "LinkFilename,Title,Col2,col4" .
```

But here my LinkFileName is not coming in the top order as the internal name of the `name` is LinkFileName.

Comment: Are you looking for reordering fields in existing content type using a PowerShell function?

Comment: Yes.that's what I am looking for and I am facing the  issue with the Name field of the  document library item.Other fields are coming properly with this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function to reorder fields in content type using PowerShell `client object model`.

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}
catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

function Reorder-ContentTypeFields()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ContentTypeName
    )

    begin{
        try
        {
            #get Client Object
            $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
            $Context.Credentials = $Credentials 

            #Load web object
            $web = $Context.Web
            $Context.Load($web)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Error while getting context. Error -->> "  + $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    process{
        try
        {
            $contentTypes = $Context.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes
            $Context.Load($contentTypes)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()
            $contentType = $contentTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq $ContentTypeName}
            $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection  
            #Col1 = Internal Name of a field
            $viewFields.Add("Col1")
            $viewFields.Add("Col2")
            $viewFields.Add("Col3")


            $contentType.FieldLinks.Reorder($viewFields)
            $contentType.Update($true)
            $Context.Load($contentType)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-Host "Fields reordered successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host ("Error while reordering fields in contet type. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    end{
        $Context.Dispose()
    }


}
```

Comment: No worries.. Always happy to help.!! :)

Comment: That StringCollection object did the trick. That was the key. :-)